# Redirect pagelayout is not showing in Pagelayout section while creating Page in Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

Im creating a new page for site redirection.In pagelayout section, Redirect Page layout is not showing.But in Masterpages and Pagelayouts ,Redirect  page layout is available.

How Can I get that pagelayout in Pagelayout section of Creating page.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

The new created page layouts are stored under `Master Page Gallery > Master pages and page layouts` by default.

To use the custom page layout to create new pages, you need to add the **Redirect Page content type** to the **Pages** list (not the Site Pages Library) via `List Settings > Content Types > Add from existing site content types > Redirect Page`.

Then you will be able to create redirect page with the “Redirect” page layout or your custom page layout.

**Note:** New redirect pages can only be created in the **Pages** list.

[image]

Comment: Hi,I have attached Redirect page content  type.But Still in pagelayout section Redirect page layout is not showing.In master pages and Pagelayouts. Redirect pagelayout is associated to redirect page contenttype. Any idea?

Comment: @SwethaParitala What is the site template you are using? Can you reproduce this issue in another site with publishing features activated?

Comment: Its a team site template. var g_wsaSiteTemplateId = 'STS#0' .

Comment: Publishing feature in Site level and site collection level is enabled.And also tried adding Redirect Pagelayout in Pagelayouts and Site templates Page,but i got access denied while clicked on OK button in Pagelayouts and Site templates Page

Comment: @SwethaParitala I don’t think “Page Layout and Site Template Settings” is the right place to go. But you are getting Access Denied possibly because “Custom Script” is disabled in your tenant/site. Try enabling the “custom script” feature in Classic SharePoint admin center > settings.